# How to select multiple max values from a sql table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get the top performers from a table, grouped by the company but can't seem to get the grouping right.

I have tried to use subqueries but this goes beyond my knowledge

I am trying to make a query that selects the rows in green. In other words I want to include the name, the company, and what they paid but only the top performers of each company.

[image: data table]

Here is the raw data

```sql
create table test (person varchar(50),company varchar(50),paid numeric);

insert into 
  test 
values 
  ('bob','a',200),
  ('jane','a',100),
  ('mark','a',350),
  ('susan','b',650),
  ('thabo','b',100),
  ('thembi','b',210),
  ('lucas','b',110),
  ('oscar','c',10),
  ('janet','c',20),
  ('nancy','c',30)
```

Comment: Please include your sample data directly in your question as text (Preferably as a `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for easy importing), not as an image.

Comment: Please do include your attempts in your question; we can't tell you where you went wrong if we can't see your attempts. Please don't provide sample data as an image either; provide is as formatted `text` (or DDL and DML statements),along with your expected results. Please do update your post so we can help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MAX()` in a subquery as

```
CREATE TABLE T(
  Person VARCHAR(45),
  Company CHAR(1),
  Paid INT
);

INSERT INTO T 
  VALUES ('Person1', 'A', 10),
         ('Person2', 'A', 20),
         ('Person3', 'B', 10);

SELECT T.*
FROM T INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Company, MAX(Paid) Paid
  FROM T
  GROUP BY Company
) TT ON T.Company = TT.Company AND T.Paid = TT.Paid;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bfb4e97eabde41ff7113c3050cbbf3a9)**

Or using a window function as

```
SELECT Person,
       Company,
       Paid
FROM 
(
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Company ORDER BY Paid DESC) RN
  FROM T
) TT
WHERE RN = 1;
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=848faf679fcc0f30e2538e9c8db8ee3d)**

Comment: Could you explain why you used the where clause 'RN = 1'?

Answer (score 0):

Here's your query.

```
select a.person, a.company, a.paid from tableA a 
inner join
(select person, company, row_number() over (partition by company order by paid desc) as rn from tableA) as t1
on t1.person = a.person and t1.company = a.company
where t1.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like

```
WITH ranked AS (SELECT person, company, paid
                     , rank() OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY paid DESC) AS rnk
                FROM yourtable)
SELECT person, company, paid
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY company;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rank()` function with partition by clause.
`DENSE_RANK` gives you the ranking within your ordered partition, but the ranks are consecutive. No ranks are skipped if there are ranks with multiple items.

```
   WITH cte AS (
            SELECT person, company, paid
               rank() OVER (PARTITION BY company ORDER BY paid desc) rn
            FROM  yourtable

        )

        SELECT
            *
        FROM cte
```